# Proving Skip: "(SKIP,s)⇒ s" terminates in Isabelle

Tags: terminate, isabelle

How can I show that 
     "(SKIP,s)⇒ s",
which is a rule of the Big Step Semantics, terminates in Isabelle?

Big Step Semantics is defined as follows  "(SKIP,s)⇒ s" is one command.

```
  inductive big_step :: "com × state ⇒ state ⇒ bool" where
 Skip: "(SKIP,s) ⇒ s" |
 Assign: "(x ::= a,s) ⇒ s(x := aval a s)" |
 Seq: "⟦ (c⇩1,s⇩1) ⇒ s⇩2;  (c⇩2,s⇩2) ⇒ s⇩3 ⟧ ⟹ (c⇩1;;c⇩2, s⇩1) ⇒ s⇩3" |
 IfTrue: "⟦ bval b s;  (c⇩1,s) ⇒ t ⟧ ⟹ (IF b THEN c⇩1 ELSE c⇩2, s) ⇒ t" |
 IfFalse: "⟦ ¬bval b s;  (c⇩2,s) ⇒ t ⟧ ⟹ (IF b THEN c⇩1 ELSE c⇩2, s) ⇒ t" |
```

I used the formal definition for total correctness

```
 ⊫ {P} c {Q} ≡ ∀s. P s ⟶ (∃ t. (c, s) ⇒ t ∧ Q t)
```

so that my Lemma now has the following form:

```
 lemma "skip: {P} skip {Q} ≡ ∀s. P s ⟶ (∃ t. (skip, s) ⇒ t ∧ Q t)"
```

Is that definition of the Lemma correct to show that it terminates?

Comment: Before you ask how to show it you need to think about how to express it. what is the lemma you want to show?

Comment: It’s hard to read in the comments. On StackExchange, you are encouraged to improve your question: Just click on edit and change it. Also, please use the code formatting for code.